# Is there a R function to find class of columns in a for loop

Tags: r

I have a dataframe(df). I need to find the class of each column names in a for loop. I tried with the below code but not able to get the solution

```
> df
  x y g
1 a 2 1
2 a 3 2
3 b 4 1
4 b 5 2

>for(i in colnames(df))
 {
 print(class(df$i)) }
```

The expected out put is

```
> "factor","integer","integer"
```

Because class of x is a factor and other 2 are integers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve that with a loop,

```
for(i in colnames(df))
 {
 print(class(df[,i])) 
}
```

But actually you can do the very same thing with `sapply` as,

`saplly(df,class)`

Comment: Hi Maydin . Perfect and thanks. But it was not working for df$i ? Ideally it should work right?

Comment: No, you can't do that. It is not working with the R ' s syntax.